# Add and Update DNS Records in Route 53 to Cloudfront with Serverless Framework

Tags: dns, amazon-route53, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I'm currently working on expanding [this repo](https://github.com/GitGangGuy/serverless-sapper-edge). It contains source code to deploy a sapper/svelte webapp with the Serverless Framework to AWS. I'm thinking about how to expand the `serverless.yml` to include Route53 DNS routing to Cloudfront, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. The [serverless-domain-manager](https://github.com/amplify-education/serverless-domain-manager) plugin seems to be designed for Route53 to API Gateway routing, but I'm deploying my app only with Cloudfront, an S3 bucket and an Lambda@Edge handler server-side-rendering the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar [here](https://github.com/erezrokah/gatsby-netlify-cms-aws/blob/8ade583d7c02e7769dd685ca64c10851c09f51cf/serverless.yml#L215).

I've trimmed the `serverless.yml` for the relevant parts:

```
WebAppCloudFrontDistribution:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    DependsOn:
      - WebAppS3Bucket
    Properties:
    DistributionConfig:
        ### content trimmed
        Aliases:
          - 'www.example.com'
        ### content trimmed
        ViewerCertificate:
          AcmCertificateArn: 'CertificateArn' # in the linked repo I'm using a plugin to auto generate the certificate
          SslSupportMethod: sni-only
WebsiteDNSName:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
    Properties:
    HostedZoneId: 'HostedZoneId' # Taken from the AWS Console
    RecordSets:
      - Name: 'www.example.com'
        Type: A
        AliasTarget:
            HostedZoneId: Z2FDTNDATAQYW2
            DNSName: !GetAtt [WebAppCloudFrontDistribution, DomainName]
            EvaluateTargetHealth: false
```

Comment: Excuse my very late answer, but when I add your snippet from the repo to my project I end up with the following warning during deployment: `A valid file to satisfy the declaration 'file(certinfo.yml):CertificateArn' could not be found.`. Why isn't this working? (Encountered at the viewer certificate place, `AcmCertificateArn: ${file(${self:custom.cert}):CertificateArn}`).

Comment: You'll need to run `serverless create-cert --stage $STAGE` to first create the certificate file using the plugin. You'll see a warning while running the `serverless create-cert` but you can ignore it since the file will be generated after the command is executed. Then once you run `serverless deploy` the file will be available.

Comment: I'm curious: How can I get serverless to redirect 'example.com' to 'www.example.com'?

Comment: I think you should be able to use `- Name: 'example.com'`